# ionic2 http get Loads the same data regardless there are some changes from data API

Tags: angular, ionic2

I got some problems with loading data with ionic 2 http get, Yet it loads and display successful but after adding some data still display the same. I tried to use Observers but it did not work,maybe i dont know how to use it well...When i clear cache from browser manually it works fine,Hope to hear from u soon.Here is my codes:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController,NavParams,AlertController,LoadingController,ToastController } from 'ionic-angular'; import {Http} from '@angular/http'; import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage'; import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner'; import {Observable} from 'rxjs/observable';


@Component({   selector: 'page-home',   templateUrl: 'home.html' }) export class HomePage { username; mypass; transactions:any;   constructor(public storage:Storage,public navCtrl: NavController,public http:Http,public navParams: NavParams)  { }


ionViewDidEnter() {

     this.storage.ready().then(() => 
     {

       this.storage.get('credentials').then((val) => 
       {
          this.today(val['username'],val['mypass']);
          this.username=val['username'];
          this.mypass=val['mypass'];
       });


     }); }



 today(user,pass)   {   

    //I WILL QUERY PROCESSED ONE
    this.http.get(myDataJSONApiUrl).map(res=>res.json()).subscribe(     (data)=>    {
        this.transactions=data;
        console.log(data);      },      (err)=>     {
       console.log(err);    });

   }


}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. You can [edit] your question to format a [mcve] code properly.

Comment: not clear, where data is displaying, where you'r adding some data?

Comment: data is displayed on home.html,the one above is home.ts...in home.And the problem is just cached data apper all the time until i clear browser cache.

Comment: Well how is this code related? Where do you get data, is it `today()`-method? Where do you add data?

Comment: Yeah I'm getting data from today() function by using http get with subscriber method,,I tried to put them  on provider/service and return json response then to home.ts i used subscribe method and still bring about the same results, i tried to use observers with setInterval but still brings about the same result until u clear browser cache...SO THE MAIN PROBLEM HERE IS HOW CAN I CLEAR CACHE IN IONIC 2,,,In ionic 1 was just by adding cache-view="false" in specific view

Comment: Okay, it's still not clear where you are adding data? Where you are adding data in the component, after doing that, why not call `today()` again so you get the updated list?

Comment: I tried so many times to call it again but still the same result.. It seems the problem here is just the view is cached, then how to disable caching in ionic 2,,i used to use the same procedure in ionic 1,ofcoz no problem in fetching data here,, but the problem is caching,, new data comes after clearing browser cache memory ,,SO HOW TO DISABLE CACHING IN IONIC 2

Comment: Try `changeDetectorRef` if for some reason the changes are not caught. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html Inject it in the constructor and then use the `detectChanges` function and call it after you have called `today` again after making changes

Answer (score 0):

Just by appending Random Number to the Url i solved the problem.Much thanks to this Man(https://forum.ionicframework.com/users/Sujan12).

Random number appends the new varriable on url every time and make it new,so it seems like hacking trick to the Url,

var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
 return this.http.get("path/to/url&random="+random).map(res => res.json());